# A main character died. Was there something I could do?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear V The Phantom Pain, I saved a main character who was wounded, and so was sent in the infirmary automatically.

The medical wing just opened, so I took care to reassign every one so he would receive care.

But I just received a message that he died.

> The character was Malak.

Did I do something wrong? Should I have leveled up my medical staff earlier, or is this normal?

Comment: Please remember, spoilers are not to be used in a way that makes the body unreadable, without them. To use spoilers correctly, the rest of the question should make sense, without them. For any users able to answer, keep in mind that the title makes it obvious that there are spoilers, and since answers do not show up without directly accessing the question, spoiler tags are not needed.

Comment: We should also not be rewording questions to use spoilers to dance around the question.  The original question was *fine*.  No spoiler tags were needed, and I encourage the asker to roll back the edits to the original revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happen to me as well. I just re-did the mission and saved him again. Only this time i put him in the SickBay so he would heal. Youll notice the Injured bar goes down after a period of time and then he will be healthy and ready to go. Hope this helped